# Using PowerMock with Cucumber

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, cucumber, powermock

I've written a JUnit test that uses Mockito and PowerMock to mock some classes. I'm trying to convert it a Cucumber test, but the static PowerMock features don't work.

Extracts of the two relevant Cucumber classes:

**Runner**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class JWTValidatorBDDTest {
}
```

**Steps Class**

```
public class JWTValidatorCukeTest {
String tokenValue;
JWTValidator jwtValidator;
MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest;

@Before
public void before() throws IOException {
    this.mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(JWTAuthConnectionManager.class);
    BDDMockito.given(JWTAuthConnectionManager.postToken(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).willReturn(200);
    Mockito.doReturn(200).when(JWTAuthConnectionManager.postToken(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()));
}

@Given("^a JWT token with the value (.*)")
public void a_JWT_token_with_the_value_(String token) {
    this.jwtValidator = new JWTValidator("https://test.7uj67hgfh.com/openam", "Authorization", "Bearer");
    this.tokenValue = token;
}
```

Whilst this code works within the JUnit test, it fails here - it enters the `JWTAuthConnectionManager.postToken()` method that should be mocked and then fails by executing code within there. I've tried adding the lines:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(JWTAuthConnectionManager.class)
```

to both of the above classes (although of course I can't use `RunWith` in the `Runner` class as it already has one `RunWith` annotation), but this doesn't change anything.

How do I get PowerMock to work within Cucumber?

Comment: A bit outdated question but it might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877324/breakpoints-are-not-triggered-while-debugging-gradle-cucumber-in-vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is possible now with @PowerMockRunnerDelegate annotation. I use @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Cucumber.class) and it's working. Taken an advise from here: https://medium.com/@WZNote/how-to-make-spock-and-powermock-work-together-a1889e9c5692

> Since version 1.6.0 PowerMock has support for delegating the test execution to another JUnit runner without using a JUnit Rule. This leaves the actual test-execution to another runner of your choice. For example tests can delegate to “SpringJUnit4ClassRunner”, “Parameterized” or the “Enclosed” runner.

There are also options of using @Rule: PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule(); instead of @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) (so Runner can be something else) - but the comment by  Stefan Birkner  suggests that Cucumber runner should support rules to use this and I am not sure if it does (now).

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `PowerMockRunner` because a test can only have one runner (in your case `Cucumber`). But AFAIK you can use the [PowerMockRule](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) instead of the `PowerMockRunner`.

Comment: I've added "@Rule\nPowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();" into both classes (also adding "@PrepareForTest" into both) with no change to the output.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The Cucumber runner doesn't support rules.

Comment: Could you try `@ClassRule PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();`. It looks like The Cucumber runner is supporting ClassRules.

Comment: `org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @ClassRule 'rule' must implement TestRule` and `org.junit.internal.runnes.rules.ValidationError: The @ClassRule 'rule' must be static.` I've been looking at how `@ClassRule` works but I can't find a solution.

Comment: :-( Looks like somebody has to build rule support for Cucumber: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/894